# Command line argument not recognized

Tags: command-line

Complete error code:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0>blender -b C:\Users\user\Documents\Blender\test01.blend -f1
Blender 3.0.1 (hash dc2d18018171 built 2022-01-26 01:46:57)
Read prefs: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend
Read blend: C:\Users\user\Documents\Blender\test01.blend
unknown argument, loading as file: -f1
Error: Cannot read file 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender3\-f1': No such file or directory

Blender quit
```

I'm trying to render a single frame of default cube.
I've searched this error everywhere on stack, blenderartist, reddit - no working solution to be found.

Double checked every word - there is no spaces or special character between them. Also tried running CMD as Admin.

Nothing worked.

-Downloaded this build from blender [archive](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender3.0/). (same result with the current stable build too, 3.2)

Comment: Does the official release do this?  What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: @Kirbinator
-Yes, current official stable version 3.2 does this too.
-Windows 8.1 Pro

I've used Win8.1 before too, with blender 3.1x verison, never had any problem before. But after this recent factory reset, this error came up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a space between the `-f` option and the argument `1`. Blender's manual documents this on the [Command Line Arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#argument-parsing) page.

> **Argument Parsing**
>
> Arguments must be separated by white space, eg:
>
> `blender -ba test.blend`
>
> …will exit since -ba is an unknown argument.